# UpdateCursor giving ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack?

Tags: cursor, update, valueerror

I am writing a script assigning the ADMINAREA value to the empty LOCALITY fields from TWB_Suburbs to TWB_Property layer. I am getting:

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Is anyone able to help out?

```
import arcpy
# set overwrite true so that if data already exists it overwrite
arcpy.env.OVERWRITE = True
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# make query for empty LOCALITY values
query = '"LOCALITY" = \' \''

# assign workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\data"

# make feature layer from property shape file, apply empty locality values query
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("TWB_Property.shp", "TWB_Property_Layer", query)

# make feature layer for suburbs shape file
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("TWB_Suburbs.shp", "TWB_Suburbs_Layer")

# Select empty properties in Properties layer WITHIN Suburbs layer
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management ("TWB_Property_Layer", "WITHIN", "TWB_Suburbs_Layer")

#create empty list
suburbList = []

# iterate over admin layer field values, to get it's value
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("TWB_Suburbs_Layer",["ADMINAREA"]) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        suburbList.append(row[0])
        print (row[0])

#get the number of selected land parcels
numberSuburbs = len(suburbList)

print(row[0])

# Create Update Cursor to update missing LOCALITY fields in property layer
for parcel in range (0, numberSuburbs):        
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("TWB_Property_Layer", "LOCALITY") as initialRows:
        for initialRow, rowTwo in initialRows:
                print(initialRow)
                print(rowTwo[0])
                rowTwo[0] = row[0]
                initialRows.updateRow(initialRow)

# Print number of fields updated for each suburb           
    print ('Suburb, Number of updated properties' .format(row[0], row[1]))
    print ("{row}" + str(numberSuburbs) +
           .format(row[0], row[1]))

    #report success message
    arcpy.AddMessage("Well done!")
```

Comment: Your Python logic is non-Pythonic. If you want just the first two rows, you could use `next` to request them, or you could slice the list ( which could be much slower if there are a large number of rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not provide us with the line number on which the error occurs but I am confident that it will be this one:

```
    for initialRow, rowTwo in initialRows:
```

You are getting the error because you are trying to set two variables (`initialRow` and `rowTwo`) when only one value (a tuple) is being provided by `initialRows` at each iteration of the `for` loop.